# How to make a single view with two tables alike

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello so I've these two queries alike, but at the moment to unite them in a view, i get trash or some weird multiplications.

```
SELECT ra.agno,cod_ine_reg, SUM(ra.cantidad) AS total_aprehendidos
FROM registra_aprehendidos ra JOIN comuna USING (id_pref)
JOIN provincia USING (cod_ine_prov)
JOIN region USING (cod_ine_reg)
GROUP BY ra.agno, cod_ine_reg;
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/TaFHBdo.png]

```
SELECT rd.agno,cod_ine_reg, SUM(rd.cantidad) AS total_denuncias
FROM registra_denuncias rd JOIN comuna USING (id_pref)
JOIN provincia USING (cod_ine_prov)
JOIN region USING (cod_ine_reg)
GROUP BY rd.agno, cod_ine_reg;
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/dyRe0WF.png]

Basically I can't do this, any idea on how to do it? I've tried using unite, unite all and some variants without results.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/0WXieY5.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work like this:

```
SELECT   apre.agno
        ,apre.cod_ine_reg
        ,apre.total_aprehendidos
        ,denu.total_denuncias
  FROM  (    
            SELECT ra.agno,cod_ine_reg, SUM(ra.cantidad) AS total_aprehendidos
            FROM registra_aprehendidos ra JOIN comuna USING (id_pref)
            JOIN provincia USING (cod_ine_prov)
            JOIN region USING (cod_ine_reg)
            GROUP BY ra.agno, cod_ine_reg     
         ) apre
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT rd.agno,cod_ine_reg, SUM(rd.cantidad) AS total_denuncias
            FROM registra_denuncias rd JOIN comuna USING (id_pref)
            JOIN provincia USING (cod_ine_prov)
            JOIN region USING (cod_ine_reg)
            GROUP BY rd.agno, cod_ine_reg
        ) denu
     ON apre.agno = denu.agno
    AND apre.cod_ine_reg = denu.cod_ine_reg
```

if you expect results from registra_denuncias, without matching records in registra_aprehendidos, a FULL JOIN would be the better approach like:

```
SELECT   COALESCE(apre.agno, denu.agno) as agno
        ,COALESCE(apre.cod_ine_reg, denu.cod_ine_reg) as cod_ine_reg
        ,COALESCE(apre.total_aprehendidos,0) as total_aprehendidos
        ,COALESCE(denu.total_denuncias,0) as total_denuncias
  FROM  (    
            SELECT ra.agno,cod_ine_reg, SUM(ra.cantidad) AS total_aprehendidos
            FROM registra_aprehendidos ra JOIN comuna USING (id_pref)
            JOIN provincia USING (cod_ine_prov)
            JOIN region USING (cod_ine_reg)
            GROUP BY ra.agno, cod_ine_reg     
         ) apre
FULL OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT rd.agno,cod_ine_reg, SUM(rd.cantidad) AS total_denuncias
            FROM registra_denuncias rd JOIN comuna USING (id_pref)
            JOIN provincia USING (cod_ine_prov)
            JOIN region USING (cod_ine_reg)
            GROUP BY rd.agno, cod_ine_reg
        ) denu
     ON apre.agno = denu.agno
    AND apre.cod_ine_reg = denu.cod_ine_reg
```

Comment: Totally forgot about using them as tables, thanks a lot this solves it.

Comment: @Matias you're welcome. happens to me too. and i'm always happy to help